# Replacing quotes with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a set of page soure code that has elements such as
`<p class='style1'>`, `<p class=3DMsoNormal>`, `<span style=3D'font-size:12.0pt'>`, `<p class=3DMsoNormal>`
but i want am trying to replace the all single quotes with double quotes in the all of the source code and those that dont have quotes to receive double quotes such as
`<p class=3DMsoNormal` and remove the text '3D' from all those that have it.
Below are a series of functions i tried that didn't work. Can someone help me find a solution to this? Thanks

```
<?php

// test files holds the source code
$html_part = file_get_contents('testRegex.html');

$cSeq = "/(.*)='(.*)'/";    //code sequence
$nSeq = "/(.*)="."(.*)"."/";        //new sequence

preg_match_all($cSeq, $html_part, $matches);
preg_replace($cSeq, $nSeq, $html_part);

echo $html_part;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this regex's are the way to go.

Maybe consider using a parser to read in the file, and write it back out / prettify it.

I've used [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/(.*)?='(.*)?'/","\\1=\"\\2\"",$str)
```

you need to use backreference http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: That’s not nearly enough, now you match *everything* before and after an equals sign. Your first step would be to reliably recognise tags (which is already not quite trivial).

Comment: that would be true if php didn't honor the non-greedines of the ?,  echo preg_replace("/(.*)='(.*)?'/","\\1=\"\\2\"",file_get_contents(_ _ FILE _ _)); for example

Comment: In your case `?` doesn’t indicate non-greediness, it indicates an optional text. But even if, that doesn’t help you since non-greediness doesn’t magically know what to match, you still need to specify this. You said `.*`, which is to say “match everything”. Non-greedy simply means that it does not match anything at all (I was mistaken about that part).

Comment: Amongst your comparisons, what should be the final look of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [`quoted_printable_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) instead of removing the '3D' manually.